# Is there a way to separate a variable name when writing two commands on one line in windows cmd?

Tags: windows, command

I can run two commands in one line in Windows CMD but I'd like to separate the variable name so that when I rerun the command, I just have to change the variable name one time instead of having to use my arrow keys to move around and change it twice.

Example of my code:

```
grep "string" file1.txt && sleep 10 && python script.py file1.txt
```

Normally I'll move my cursor and change file1.txt the next time I want to run this command. If I had to do this very often I would try a batch script but I'm just wondering if there is a way to isolate that variable?

Maybe something along the lines of:

```
grep "string" $1 && sleep 10 && python script.py $1 $1=file1.txt
```

This way I just have to change the variable name once. Note: the script above does not work, just trying to show what I mean by using a variable placeholder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MYTEMPVAR=“file1.txt” grep “string” $MYTEMPVAR && sleep 10 && python script.py $MYTEMPVAR
```

If you need multiple variables, just seperate them with a space.  Do NOT use a semicolon, or the variable will be gone.

```
MYTEMPA=“file1” MYTEMPB=“.txt” grep ...
```